# ListView not adding string from OutputDataReceived event (System.Diagnostics.Process)

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a program that launches a java JAR file and grabs output while it runs; (RSBot from PowerBot.org)
Everything works fine but my ListView isn't adding text from the "OutputDataReceived" event but I can display it in a MessageBox.Show(); or Debug.WriteLine();

My ListView was added to a theme class but the only things modified are not owner drawn.

```
Class GhostListView
Inherits ListView
    Sub New()
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 21, 21, 21)
        Me.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.ForeColor = Color.GhostWhite

        Me.View = Windows.Forms.View.Details
        Me.FullRowSelect = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

so nothing there is modified that would stop the following from adding to my ListView

```
Shared Sub RSBotProc_Output(sender As Object, e As DataReceivedEventArgs) Handles RSBotProcess.OutputDataReceived
    'Sub is shared because the Process is declared publicly as shared
    'Public Shared WithEvents RSBotProcess as Process = Nothing
    Functions.AddBotOutput(e)
    Functions.Log("Output Svc", "Received Output from Bot: " & e.Data)
    Debug.WriteLine("Recvd: " & e.Data)
End Sub
```

*Functions class (as used above)*

```
Public Class Functions
    Public Shared Sub Log(supplier As String, msg As String)
        Dim s(2) As String
        s(0) = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss-fff")
        s(1) = supplier
        s(2) = msg
        frmLog.GhostListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(s))
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub AddBotOutput(Args As DataReceivedEventArgs)
        Dim s(1) As String
        s(0) = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss-fff")
        s(1) = Args.Data
        frmBotOutput.GhostListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(s))
    End Sub
End Class
```

*Output in Debug*

```
Recvd: [INFO] Optimising your experience
Recvd: [INFO] Starting bot
Recvd: [INFO] Loading game
Recvd: [INFO] Unpacking client (7dea8f)
Recvd: [INFO] Starting game
```

But, my ListView is blank and the item count is 0...
I'm a little lost here, I have a feeling the problem is staring me in the face but I've been trying to squash this bug for about 20 minutes and I'm probably just skimming over the problem... I seem to do that every now and then, but even Rubber Ducky Debugging didn't help me this time.
Also, if wanted, I can upload the entire project and let someone take a look if they'd like.

***edit***

To ensure my log/addtobot were being called from the Functions class, I added a debug that outputs what is sent to the function
Output from that:

```
Functions#AddBotOutput() - Attempting to add '[INFO] Optimising your experience'
Functions#Log() - Attempting to log '[Output Svc] - Received Output from Bot: [INFO] Optimising your experience'
Recvd: [INFO] Optimising your experience
Functions#AddBotOutput() - Attempting to add '[INFO] Starting bot'
Functions#Log() - Attempting to log '[Output Svc] - Received Output from Bot: [INFO] Starting bot'
Recvd: [INFO] Starting bot
Functions#AddBotOutput() - Attempting to add '[INFO] Loading game'
Functions#Log() - Attempting to log '[Output Svc] - Received Output from Bot: [INFO] Loading game'
Recvd: [INFO] Loading game
```

Comment: You fell into a standard VB.NET trap.  Using a *type* name instead of an object reference, like frmBotOutput, is a nasty object-oriented programming blackhole.  It blows up in your face when you use it on another thread.  Your RSBotProc_Output() does not run on the UI thread.  Beyond learning about proper OOP techniques and thread-safe programming, it will take another year of your life, the quickest fix is to assign the RSBotProcess.SynchronizingObject property.

Comment: Thank you for replying with both an explanation _and_ a possible fix Hans, that's what I was looking for haha. I'll look into the SynchronizingObject, if it doesn't work I'll just look into a different method for capturing process output, however this seemed like the most efficient way for some reason.